# ver. 19.8.x以降、矩形選択後にマウス右クリックを行なうと矩形選択が解除される

Tags: emeditor

ver. 19.8.x以降、矩形選択後にマウス右クリックを行なうと矩形選択が解除されるようになっていて、矩形選択後に右クリックから番号の挿入をする際などに非常にやりにくくなっています。ver. 19.7.x以前では発生していなかったと思います。

設定で変更できるのであればやり方を教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

すみません。EmEditor 19.8.x には書いていただいた不具合がありますが、v19.9 beta (19.8.98以上) に更新して、矩形選択テキストの内側で右クリックすると、選択は解除されません。ベータ版を含む最新版に更新してお使いください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
矩形選択後にカーソルキーで1文字でも動かすと、右クリックをしても矩形選択が解除されないことがわかったので、暫定対応方法の1つとして書き添えておきます